# "Disk likely to fail soon" after updating to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, disk

I have a 7-year old Lenovo Y50 with a 1TB HDD. I have installed Ubuntu and Windows on different partitions. I am not a heavy user of my Hard Drive, but I use [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) to backup some things (some school results with a lot of folders) to Google Drive.

I updated my computer to Ubuntu 20.04 last week and, after booting up today, I got a "Disk likely to fail soon" message in the following screen:

[Disks output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcZGM.png)

I ran `sudo smartctl -x /dev/sda1` and the first results confirm this problem

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
No failed Attributes found.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (18720) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 207) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.
```

The [full results can be found here](https://pastebin.com/9043KZAB).

Beside backing up the data in my disk ¿What should I do? ¿Wait until it fails and then replace it with an authorized repairshop?

Comment: I only see the disk running hot.  Anything blocking the cooling airflow (like dust buildup)?  Anything else running hot ? (Paste sensors output in your original question).

Comment: @ubfan1 It was on the sun for a couple of minutes but not much and It was turned off. The computer doesn't feel hot, I have felt it hotter. Is the sensors output not contained in the [full results](https://pastebin.com/9043KZAB)?

Comment: Most hard drives are very simple to replace.  Google your laptop with replacing hard drive to see if it is easy.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for the advice. Any idea on why is my hard drive failing?

Comment: Age for the failing, 7 years for a laptop drive is a damn good lifetime result. Get yourself new drive and re-install and bring back the information you have on backup. If getting a SSD it will be like you have bought a new machine the difference is that great in the performance. A guide for your model. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oVgkGCNAbw

Comment: @Aldo Sayeg  Can be almost anything, age, heat, knock around, or bad reading.  Keep data back up and have replacement drive handy.  Be good time to look at SSDs for replacement.  Drive might last for some time or die tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks to all I am a little short on money so I will wait for it to bust before replacing. I have another comptuer to use.